# How to flush the DNS cache on macOS?

Tags: network, mojave, dns

I've read that `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` should flush the DNS cache on OSX (macOS Mojave).

However, this command kills processes without restarting them, and is both hard to remember and cumbersome. Also, AFAIK `dscacheutil` applies only to the directory service.

Doesn't OSX provide a command like Windows' `ipconfig /flushdns` to flush the system's DNS cache?

Answer (score 12):

`mDNSResponder` is started by `launchd` whenever a DNS query is performed in the system. So it will restart the next time some process performs a DNS query.

Killing this process is not required though, sending the `HUP` signal with

`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

[already flushes the cache](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202516). This hasn't change up to 10.15.

`dscacheutil` is only for 10.6 and you need a different command from 10.10.0 to 10.10.3, that's because Apple wanted to replace `mDNSResponder` with 10.10, yet the replacement had so many problems that they reverted back in 10.10.4 and stayed with  `mDNSResponder` ever since.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks for the additional information, too.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a shortcut but you could easily put the one-liner

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

in a text file, name it DNSflush.sh for example, and use that as your command. Make the file executable and then run it from the terminal. I just did this and named the file simply DNSFlush and it worked fine.

The sudo command required me to enter my password.

Comment: You can also add commands to restart the two services you killed.

Comment: It looks like the code above is combining what to do if you are running several different versions of MacOS. On osX 10.10.4 and above all you should have to do is sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder  See https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+To+Clear+Your+DNS+Cache

Comment: @ThomasNelson. I got that command from https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214981288-Flushing-your-DNS-cache-in-Mac-OS-X-and-Linux It said it was for Sierra or newer.

Comment: @jmh - but if I kill processes, don't I need to restart then again? Otherwise, I guess, I will have cleared the DNS cache, but won't have any DNS 